# Change RDP with Invoke-WmiMethod

Tags: powershell, wmi, rdp

I want change RDP port with WMI method but my code doesn't work and I don't know why.

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Class StdRegprov -Name SetDWORDvalue -ArgumentList 2147483650,"System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp", "PortNumber", 3354
```

I get this after execute in PowerShell:

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
ReturnValue      : 5
PSComputerName   :
```

But nothing changed?

Answer (score 1):

This right here indicates your problem:

```
ReturnValue      : 5
```

Return code 5 means "access denied". Your user does not have permission to write to that registry location. You probably need to run the code "as administrator".

With that said, PowerShell provides direct access to the registry. You don't need WMI for that.

```
$reg   = 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp'
$name  = 'PortNumber'
$value = 3354

New-ItemProperty -Path $reg -Name $name -Value $value -Type DWORD -Force | Out-Null
```

You still need to run this with a user who has write access to the registry key, though.